# django rest framework returning list instead of dict after serializering data

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am returning some data but instead of dict I am getting list in return

my `serializer.py` file

```
class CommitteeDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Committee
        fields = ['id','com_name', 'com_members_limit', 'com_amount_per_month', 
                 'com_starting_date', 'com_join_id', 'com_status']
```

my `views.py`

```
serializer = CommitteeDetailsSerializer(get_committee, many=True)
```

I am getting this data list

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "msg": "Done.",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "com_name": "My second Committee",
            "com_members_limit": 4,
            "com_amount_per_month": 1000,
            "com_starting_date": "2022-05-04",
            "com_join_id": "GR9PKKOX65",
            "com_status": "pending"
        }
    ]
}
```

what I want is dict here in data `{}`

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py in the serializer you passed many=True, hence its returning a list. Remove that and you should get one single object serialized instead of a list.

Comment: after remvoing I am getting the error "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `com_name` "

Comment: That's a different error, Make sure that model Committee have this field.